# How to avoid insertion where overlapping timestamp found in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to check if the timestamp call_start and call_end according to a customer is not the same, so that no customer is engaged on two calls at the same time.

I am inserting some customer_id here

```
for rec in (select t.agent_id, t.call_start, t.call_end, t.aht, t.customer_id from temp_sdg_calls t) loop
    insert into aa_dev.sdg_calls
    values(rec.agent_id, rec.call_start, rec.call_end, rec.aht, (select customer_id from aa_dev.sdg_calls order by random() limit 1));
end loop;
```

I want to insert customerid from aa_dev.sdg_calls only when there is no similar time customer has called for example I don't need such scenario below. So to avoid this I want to check it at the time of insertion, if such a scenario occurs then pick another customerid and insert it here

| call_start | call_end | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-16 09:12:40 | 2020-11-16 09:13:05 | 2345 |
| 2020-11-16 09:12:50 | 2020-11-16 09:13:10 | 2345 |

Initially, the table is like this

| call_start | call_end | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-16 09:12:40 | 2020-11-16 09:13:05 | 2345 |
| 2020-11-16 09:12:50 | 2020-11-16 09:13:10 | null |

I have to insert in the place of null value and Im picking it up randomly.
I tried this.

```
for rec in (select t.agent_id, t.call_start, t.call_end, t.aht, t.customer_id from temp_sdg_calls t) loop
    while rec.call_start not between(t.call_start, t.call_end) loop
        insert into aa_dev.sdg_calls
        values(rec.agent_id, rec.call_start, rec.call_end, rec.aht, (select customer_id from aa_dev.sdg_calls order by random() limit 1));
      end loop;
end loop;
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but why the slow and inefficient row-by-row inserts? Why not use `insert into insert into aa_dev.sdg_calls (...) select ... from  temp_sdg_calls`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because I want to insert row by row, every row shall have a different id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select the best datatype: When you have a start and end timestamp, it looks like a range. And PostgreSQL does offer this datatype, a timestamp range, tsrange.

Every range has a lower bound and an upper bound, the start and the end. Then there are also the inclusive and exclusive bounds, represented by [ and ] for inclusive and ( and ) for the exclusive bounds.

Most of the time I use a function to create the range, that would be the function tsrange() in this case:

```
SELECT tsrange('2021-01-20 10:00', '2021-01-20 11:00', '[)');
```

And the result:

> [2021-01-20 10:00:00,2021-01-20 11:00:00)

Meaning a start at 2021-01-20 10:00:00 and end at 2021-01-20 11:00:00, but without including 2021-01-20 11:00:00. So basically 2021-01-20 11:00:00 minus 1 microsecond.

With this datatype, you also get the option to create an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT), to avoid overlapping ranges. This is using the btree_gist extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

CREATE TABLE sdg_calls (
  customer_id int4 NOT NULL,
  ts_call tsrange NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT unique_customer_call EXCLUDE USING gist (customer_id public.gist_int4_ops WITH pg_catalog.=, ts_call pg_catalog.range_ops WITH pg_catalog.&&)
)
;

INSERT INTO sdg_calls(customer_id, ts_call) VALUES(1, tsrange('2021-02-01 10:00', '2021-02-01 10:15','[)'));
INSERT INTO sdg_calls(customer_id, ts_call) VALUES(1, tsrange('2021-02-01 10:15', '2021-02-01 10:30','[)'));
```

Next one will fail:

```
INSERT INTO sdg_calls(customer_id, ts_call) VALUES(1, tsrange('2021-02-01 10:25', '2021-02-01 10:45','[)'));
```

You now get many [range-functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) and operators for your daily work. This is especially handy when working on planning software, making reservations, etc.

Comment: Can you give a descriptive answer please?

Comment: @Chloe: See above